# WiFi deauthenticating by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.10 on my Dell XPS and I am unable to connect to Wi-Fi. I found the error message on the title in the System log file and this explains the re-authentication pop-ups however this is looks to be a symptom of an underlying issue.

Interestingly, it worked the first time I connected to Wi-Fi using the inbuilt wireless NIC of my laptop, and the same was true when using an external USB wireless card.
Any ideas as to what might be causing thing?

Thanks,

TheCube

Comment: I have not tried replacing networkmanager however I am not sure what alternatives are available.

Comment: I have had a look at Software and updates for possible driver updates but found nothing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: This was resolved by using the 2.4GHz WiFi and not 5GHz